# Crystal Reports Formula Field Issue

Tags: asp-classic, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have crystal reports and in formula editor, based on date.

```
If {?PDATERANGE1} <> "" AND {?PDATERANGE2} <> "" Then
    ToText(DateValue({?PDATERANGE1}), "MMM d, yyyy") & " - " & ToText(DateValue({?PDATERANGE2}), "MMM d, yyyy")
```

I am calling this from ASP and PDATERANGE1 and PDATERANGE2 are "10/10/2001" and "10/12/2001".

I am getting the following error.

Bad date format string. Details: errorKind Error in File {B6624BE5-D6DA-469B-A635-9FE86B125492}.rpt: Error in formula dt_range: 'If {?PDATERANGE1} <> "" AND {?PDATERANGE2} <> "" Then ' Bad date format string. Details: errorKind

Could someone please tell me what is wrong? I am not a crystal reports developer.

Comment: not sure, that date format string works for me.

Comment: @kalls: Are you setting the values to be `10/10/2001` and `10/12/2001`, or `"10/10/2001"` and `"10/12/2001"` ?

Comment: @MarkBannister My money is on this being the culprit. Might want to add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values of `{?PDATERANGE1}` and `{?PDATERANGE2}` include double quotes - so that they are `"10/10/2001"` and `"10/12/2001"` respectively - then these double quotes need to be removed (so that they become `10/10/2001` and `10/12/2001` respectively).

Comment: Thanks @Mark Bannister. I hard coded the date without the double quotes and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because "" is not a valid date. Are the paramaters optional and you're checking whether they have values?

In crystal you have to use function hasvalue({?parameter}) though optional parameters tend to cause real issue so i avoid them like the plague!